# Selenium can't find element by id

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to create a simple test with Selenium. I used this code before and it worked fine. Somehow it stopped working when I changed to a new machine. I tried adding some code to wait until the element is visible, but it didn't work out.

I just try to find an element by its id, move to this element and click it. Somehow the code doesn't find the element at all.

Here is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class SeleniumBasicTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);

    driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("menu-item-33")));

    System.out.println("Successfully opened the website www.Store.Demoqa.com");

    WebElement producCategorytMenu = driver.findElement(By.id("menu-item-33"));

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(producCategorytMenu).perform();
    builder.click(producCategorytMenu).perform();

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    System.out.println("quiting test...");
    driver.quit();
  }

}
```

This is the exception I'm receiving:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == menu-item-33 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 315 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.3.0', revision: 'b526bd5b41', time: '2017-03-07 19:26:04 +0000'
System info: host: 'CMTCLX62137', ip: '53.19.245.167', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{se:ieOptions={browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, ignoreZoomSetting=true, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, ie.useLegacyFileUploadDialogHandling=false, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:37146/, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true}, browserName=internet explorer, pageLoadStrategy=normal, javascriptEnabled=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 1e1740a9-00a2-4b92-814a-1979cfcef8e0
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=menu-item-33}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:371)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:420)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at com.mytest.SeleniumBasicTest.main(SeleniumBasicTest.java:22)
```

And here is the part of the HTML that has the menu:

```
    <nav class="group" id="main-nav">
            <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-11 current_page_item menu-item-15"><span class="before">&nbsp;</span><a href="http://store.demoqa.com/"><span></span>Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpsc_product_category menu-item-has-children menu-item-33 has_children"><span class="before">&nbsp;</span><a href="http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/"><span></span>Product Category</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpsc_product_category menu-item-34"><span class="before">&nbsp;</span><a href="http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/accessories/"><span></span>Accessories</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpsc_product_category menu-item-35"><span class="before">&nbsp;</span><a href="http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/imacs/"><span></span>iMacs</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpsc_product_category menu-item-36"><span class="before">&nbsp;</span><a href="http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/ipads/"><span></span>iPads</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpsc_product_category menu-item-37"><span class="before">&nbsp;</span><a href="http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/iphones/"><span></span>iPhones</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-38" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpsc_product_category menu-item-38"><span class="before">&nbsp;</span><a href="http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/ipods/"><span></span>iPods</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-39" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpsc_product_category menu-item-39"><span class="before">&nbsp;</span><a href="http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/macbooks/"><span></span>MacBooks</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-16 has_children"><span class="before">&nbsp;</span><a><span></span>#0 (no title)</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><span class="before">&nbsp;</span><a><span></span>#0 (no title)</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><span class="before">&nbsp;</span><a><span></span>#0 (no title)</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-72" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpsc_product_category menu-item-72"><span class="before">&nbsp;</span><a href="http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/"><span></span>All Product</a></li>
</ul>
```

Source: http://store.demoqa.com/

Anyone knows what might be happening?
I've read all the similar questions here on StackOverflow, tried every single option and still it doesn't find an element that is clearly there.

Comment: try ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable, instead of visibility. But actually code should work

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

I don't see any errors in your code block. But you may consider to use `elementToBeClickable` method instead of `visibilityOfElementLocated` while you induce `ExplicitWait`. Additionally, instead of locating the `li` element with `id` as `menu-item-33`, you can consider to locate the `a` tag of the element. Finally, the `a` tag will receive the normal `Java` click and you won't be needing to use `Actions` class. Here is your own code with some simple tweaks:

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    public class Q44952318 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {


            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer_32.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            cap.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
            cap.setCapability("platform", "WIN8"); 
            cap.setCapability("version", "11"); 
            cap.setCapability("browserName", "internet explorer");
            cap.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings",1);
            cap.setCapability("nativeEvents","false");
            cap.setCapability("requireWindowFocus","true");
            cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
            WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
            driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");
            System.out.println("Successfully opened the website www.Store.Demoqa.com");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
            WebElement product = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@id='menu-item-33']/a")));
            product.click();
            System.out.println("quiting test...");
            driver.quit();

        }

    }
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: It keeps giving me this exception:



`WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //li[@id='menu-item-33']/a)
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find elements on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//li[@id='menu-item-33']/a}
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor10.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)`

Comment: @AlexanderRumanovsk Actually, both your code and my code works as expected at my end. I simply reduced your lines of code. I suppose the problem is with the Selenium v3.3.0. Consider bumping up to stable GA Selenium 3.4.0. Thanks

Comment: tried Selenium 3.4.0 and still the same thing. Do you think it might be because I'm using my mobile internet as a router to test it? (I don't have a wifi availabe here)

Comment: can you ensure that you are using `IEDriverServer.exe` of release 3.4.0 & your Java & JRE version is up-to-date? `sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor10.newInstance` is a typical Java error and not related to Selenium. Thanks

Comment: `mobile internet as a router` must not an issue. Actually both our code block works at my end. I simply removed the redundancy from your code. Thanks

Comment: I just downloaded IEDriverServer.exe from selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0.zip, and I'm using java 1.8.0_31

Comment: @AlexanderRumanovsk `Mobile Internet` Please induce ImplicitlyWait or ExplicitlyWait you will see off the error. Thanks

Comment: Check out my updated code and let me know the status.

Comment: Still the same problem. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked fine on my computer also. So my guess is that there is something different in the IE configuration. As you said your issues started when you switched computers. Which means that your current IE might not be configured. Also would be great if you could post your current IE version.

As you are using IE it needs to have set some of the settings before you can run tests on it.

1. Do you have "Enhanced Protected Mode" disabled in the IE settings? It is under advanced tab and under security. It has to be disabled
2. You must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value.
   Enabled protected mode for all 4 zones (Internet, Local Intranet, Trusted sites, Restricted sites) [image]

Comment: IE is version 11.0.9600.18697. I think it might be the protected mode. It's not enabled for Local Intranet and Trusted Sites. Just for Internet. But I can't change that because I don't have admin rights on this machine.
Can I fix this in the code?

Comment: Don't think there is a good solution to fix it by code. The things that I was looking at didn't work for me. I would try to get the admin rights on the device. If you really want to try something then. Some guys are suggesting using the following capability, but use this on your own risk and it is highly unreliable. caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
        true);

Comment: Tried ignoring the security domains. Still nothing. This is really strange. The same code works perfectly at any other computer.

Comment: @AlexanderRumanovsk Do those computers have all protected modes enabled on their IE?

Comment: Yes, they do. I think this might be my problem, but ignoring the security domains still didn't work.

Comment: @AlexanderRumanovsk As I said, the security domains is unreliable. I would suggest getting the admin rights for the device. This seems to be the most reliable option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148583/discussion-between-madis-kangro-and-alexander-rumanovsk).

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that my problem is caused by IE's Protected Mode not being set to the same option on all zones. It does not work even ignoring this configurations using:

```
  DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
  cap.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings",true);
  cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
```

I changed it on another computer that the code was working and had the same problem described in the question. Changed back and it worked again.

So, it seems like there is no way to surpass the Protected Mode configuration on the code.